# How to detect touch outside textInput in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm make a react native app that require something like this:
[image]

When i click some input, the border of textInput change to orange color, and when click other textInput or every else the screen, it return white like normal, but i don't know how to capture the outside touch of TextInput, how can we do that?

Comment: You can use onBlur props of textinput for that or react native paper  has prebuilt feature you can also use that.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your `View` in [TouchableWithoutFeedback](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback) and call `Keyboard.dismiss()` as prop. Like this:

```js
import {Keyboard} from 'react-native'
...

return(
    ...
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <TextInput 
                keyboardType='numeric'
                onBlur={() => console.log("Focus Lost")} //when you touch outside the textInput this will call
            />
        </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
)
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, but i want to detect outside touch, for example, the orange line in the input will be grey when i click outside

Comment: You can use the `onBlur` prop in `TextInput`, i updated the answer.

Comment: It wont work , when i set flex:1 on view the textInput disappear